# How do I use unsized types/traits in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have the following

```
trait T {}
type Iter = fn() -> Iterator<Item = T>;

fn func(iter: Iter) {
    for a in iter() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I would like `iter` to return an Iterator with move semantics, so I shouldn't have to return `&Iterator`. Problem is, `Iterator` is a trait, so it's unsized. The above code gets a compile error saying that Iterable does not satisfy the Sized trait because all local variables have to be statically sized.

On top of this, `T` is also a trait, therefore unsized, so I can't bind `a` to it either because it's unsized.

I'm new to Rust so this is really tripping me up. How do I use unsized types?

Answer (score 4):

You probably shouldn't use unsized types at all here. Use generics instead:

```
trait Foo {} // T is a common name for type parameters, so use a different name

fn func<I, F>(iter: F) where I: Iterator, I::Item: Foo, F: FnOnce() -> I {
  for a in iter() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Check out the book chapters on [generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/generics.html) and [`Fn*` traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html).

And by the way, accepting a function doesn't seem very useful, since you just call it once at the start. It seems much simpler to write the function like this:

```
fn func<I>(iter: I) where I: Iterator, I::Item: Foo {
  for a in iter {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `Iterator` still unsized though? I would think you may have to `Box` it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Oops, you're right.

Comment: What are the performance implications of boxing/unboxing unsized types. Is this something I can use in performance sensitive code?

Comment: @jz87 The code I posted above (using generics) has no run time overhead since specialized code for the specific iterator type and `Foo` implementation passed. Boxing the iterator and/or the `Foo` objects would require additional memory allocation and dynamic dispatch on every method call and iteration, which does have a non-zero (though not necessarily very high, depending on what you're doing) performance impact.

Comment: What if I have a recursive struct? Like struct A { content: T, children: Option<A> }, in this case, I can't use generics because that would bind the content of all the children to the same concrete type. So is boxing the only way in this scenario?

Comment: The code example as given doesn't work.  It's syntactically invalid, has a missing generic parameter, and is still trying to return an unsized type.

Comment: @jz87 Generics are for dealing with *traits*. They're not a magic wand removing boxing. Yes, you need some kind of indirection for recursive types.

Comment: @DK. Ugh, that's what I get for posting late at night. Corrected now, for good.

Answer (score 2):

Unsized types only "work" if there is an additional level of indirection involved. Example:

```
trait Ttait {}
fn foo(x: Trait) {}      // error: x would be unsized which is not allowed
fn bar(x: &Trait) {}     // OK: x is just a reference
fn baz(x: Box<Trait>) {} // OK: x is just an "owning pointer"
```

But instead of using traits as types, you should probably prefer to use traits as *bounds* for type *parameters* of generic functions and structs:

```
fn generic<Type: Trait>(x: Type) {}
```

This is actually not a function but a *family* of functions. For each type `Type` that implements `Trait` the compiler will create a special version of `generic` if needed. If you have some value `x` of a concrete type that implements `Trait` and write `generic(x)` you will be invoking a function that is created especially for that type which is unsized. This is called "monomorphization".

So, traits have two uses. They act as unsized types (for trait objects, dynamic dispatch, dynamic polymorphism) as well as type bounds for generic code (static dispatch, static polymorphism). My suggestion would be to avoid trait objects if you can and prefer generic code.

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, let me show you one possibility:

```
trait Trait {
    fn foo(&self);
}

fn func<'x,I>(iterable: I) where I: IntoIterator<Item = &'x Trait> {
    for a in iterable {
        a.foo();
    }
}

struct Example;

impl Trait for Example {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("Example::foo()");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let arr = [Example, Example];
    func(arr.iter().map(|x| x as &Trait));
}
```

This is an example which demonstrates both kinds of trait uses. `func` is generic over the kinds of iterables it takes but uses dynamic dispatch to invoke the right `foo` function. This is probably closest to what you were trying to do.

You could also go "full generic" (avoiding the dynamic dispatch for the `foo` calls. See delnan's answer) or "full dynamic" (making `func` agnostic about what kind of iterator it actually deals with at runtime). With more context we can probably make better suggestions.